# Using while-loops - how to code number of random ellipses over canvas

Tags: python, processing

How do you draw random ellipses over a canvas using while-loops?

Example being: if the user types in 10, then 10 circles should appear on the canvas in random places.

if the user types in 5 then 5 ellipse should appear on the canvas also in different places.

I believe this may be the code to start with to generate the random () function.

```
x = int(random(0, 200))
y = int(random(0, 200))
```

However i do not know how to expand further than that.

Comment: I'd start by googling something like "python while loop" or "python for loop".

Comment: @Vex143 stack is not a place to get your work done, please check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

```
void setup() {
  size(300, 300); 
  noLoop();  // we only want 5 not hundreds 
}

void draw() {

  int i = 0;
  int sizeOfEllipse = 0;
  int xPos = 0;
  int yPos = 0;


  while (i < 5) {
    xPos = int(random(width));
    yPos = int(random(height));
    sizeOfEllipse = int(random(10, 50)); // minimum size of 10 max 50
    ellipse(xPos, yPos, sizeOfEllipse, sizeOfEllipse); // circles are a special case of an ellipse
    i = i + 1;
  }
}
```